# What is the difference between a "Phone" calendar and a "Local" calendar in Android?

Tags: sync, calendar, delete, cleanup, data

I've been helping a friend with their Android phone. They have 3 different types of calendars, according to their ["Business Calendar 2"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.bizcal) app:

1. Calendars synced to a Google account
2. "Phone" calendar (it has 1, and no more can be added)
3. "Local" calendars (it has 1, but more can be added)

What is the difference between a "Phone" calendar and a "Local" calendar, and how can one remove all the data in the "Phone" calendar?

Comment: I would assume that the type "local calendar" is specific to the Business Calendar 2 app. May be a calendar that is only accessible from within Business Calendar 2? Better check the help pages of Business Calendar 2 or ask it's author.

Comment: @Robert Thanks Robert. Before posting, I had scoured the BC2 help pages, but unfortunately didn't find anything relevant. I seem to recall that Android has several different types of calendars, each with a different identifying string. If that sounds vague, it's because it is... I just can't recall all the details!  I remember discovering this from experimentation I performed over 5 years ago.  IIRC, one ID was for a "Phone" calendar, and then you can have almost an unlimited number of IDs for "Local" calendars and synced calendars. It was many years ago, and so I don't recall all the details.